# Is there a way of using Markdown in web development by tagging div?

Tags: html, web, markdown

Is it possible to use Markdown on website without manually parsing the content ?

I saw [this tool](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) that can be used to create website with markdown, but I need to parse the content manually by running some commands like `marked.parse()`.

I don't want to parse everything manually, I want the content to be straight parsed from the website by using "class".
for example if I add `class="markdown"` then the content will get parsed, something like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://<some website>"></script>
  <title>Marked in the browser</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="markdown">
    # Hellow World !
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: _"Is there any tool that does that ?"_ Short answer. No. There is no approach or tool which can fulfill the OP's wish by pure presentational layer magic. The OP on client side always needs a JavaScript based parsing and DOM rendering approach similar to the tool, the OP is mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above comment ...

> *"Is there any tool that does that ?"* Short answer. No. There is no approach or tool which can fulfill the OP's wish by pure presentational layer magic. The OP on client side always needs a JavaScript based parsing and DOM rendering approach similar to the tool, the OP is mentioning."_

Thus said, of cause the OP can classify any markdown content like with the OP's example code.

In order to then present the parsed content to the consumer of a JavaScript enabled client, the OP needs an additional script which utilizes e.g. the also already mentioned `marked.parse` method.

Something similar to this ...

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('.markdown')
  .forEach(elmNode =>
    elmNode.innerHTML = marked.parse(elmNode.textContent)
  );
```

```css
body { zoom: .8; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/markedjs/marked@bf1295a499c60abc096124ab33804071cb8d89fe/marked.min.js"></script>

<div class="markdown">
  # Hellow World !
</div>
<div class="markdown">
  ## markdown render test
</div>
<div class="markdown">

  ## Usage

  ### Warning:  Marked does not [sanitize](https://marked.js.org/#/USING_ADVANCED.md#options) the output HTML. Please use a sanitize library, like [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) (recommended), [sanitize-html](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html) or [insane](https://github.com/bevacqua/insane) on the output HTML! 

  ## Demo

  Checkout the [demo page](https://marked.js.org/demo/) to see marked in action ⛹️

  ## Docs

  Our [documentation pages](https://marked.js.org) are also rendered using marked 

  Also read about:

  * [Options](https://marked.js.org/#/USING_ADVANCED.md)
  * [Extensibility](https://marked.js.org/#/USING_PRO.md)

</div>
```